# Помогите найти ошибку в Ubuntu 20,04

Tags: ubuntu

Ситуация такая. Установил Ubuntu 20.04. Через некоторое время система зависает полностью без каких либо вариантов перезагрузил. Подумал это единичный случай. Перезагрузил включил музыку в наушниках сижу работаю через 2 часа опять завис, но музыка играет дальше я не понял, подумал может порты USB зависли. Засек время на мониторе но часы не двигаются, музыка воспроизводится дальше. Порыскал в интернете как смотреть логи ошибок. Куча вариаторов, но что то не то. Согрешил на образ который был, зашел на официальный сайт Ubuntu скачал от туда, переустановил заново, но проблема не решилась.

Поделитесь пожалуйста дельным советом в какую сторону смотреть

```
> System Information


root@imht:/home/mirzaaliev# sudo lshw -short
H/W path       Device     Class          Description
====================================================
                          system         System Product Name (ASUS_MB_CNL)
/0                        bus            ROG STRIX Z390-H GAMING
/0/0                      memory         64KiB BIOS
/0/3f                     memory         16GiB System Memory
/0/3f/0                   memory         [empty]
/0/3f/1                   memory         [empty]
/0/3f/2                   memory         16GiB DIMM DDR4 Synchronous 3466 MHz (0,3 ns)
/0/3f/3                   memory         [empty]
/0/4a                     memory         384KiB L1 cache
/0/4b                     memory         1536KiB L2 cache
/0/4c                     memory         9MiB L3 cache
/0/4d                     processor      Intel(R) Core(TM) i5-9600K CPU @ 3.70GHz
/0/100                    bridge         8th Gen Core Processor Host Bridge/DRAM Registers
/0/100/1                  bridge         Xeon E3-1200 v5/E3-1500 v5/6th Gen Core Processor PCIe Controller (x16)
/0/100/1/0                display        GF116 [GeForce GTX 550 Ti]
/0/100/1/0.1              multimedia     GF116 High Definition Audio Controller
/0/100/14                 bus            Cannon Lake PCH USB 3.1 xHCI Host Controller
/0/100/14/0    usb1       bus            xHCI Host Controller
/0/100/14/0/2             multimedia     ROG Strix Fusion Wireless
/0/100/14/0/3             input          Gaming Mouse G303
/0/100/14/0/5             input          USB Device
/0/100/14/0/6             input          Scorpion K10
/0/100/14/1    usb2       bus            xHCI Host Controller
/0/100/14.2               memory         RAM memory
/0/100/16                 communication  Cannon Lake PCH HECI Controller
/0/100/17                 storage        Cannon Lake PCH SATA AHCI Controller
/0/100/1b                 bridge         Cannon Lake PCH PCI Express Root Port #17
/0/100/1c                 bridge         Cannon Lake PCH PCI Express Root Port #1
/0/100/1d                 bridge         Cannon Lake PCH PCI Express Root Port #9
/0/100/1f                 bridge         Z390 Chipset LPC/eSPI Controller
/0/100/1f.3               multimedia     Cannon Lake PCH cAVS
/0/100/1f.4               bus            Cannon Lake PCH SMBus Controller
/0/100/1f.5               bus            Cannon Lake PCH SPI Controller
/0/100/1f.6    eno1       network        Ethernet Connection (7) I219-V
/0/1                      system         PnP device PNP0c02
/0/2                      system         PnP device PNP0c02
/0/3                      communication  PnP device PNP0501
/0/4                      system         PnP device PNP0c02
/0/5                      generic        PnP device INT3f0d
/0/6                      system         PnP device PNP0c02
/0/7                      system         PnP device PNP0c02
/0/8                      system         PnP device PNP0c02
/0/9                      system         PnP device PNP0c02
/0/a           scsi0      storage        
/0/a/0.0.0     /dev/sda   disk           120GB WDC WDS120G2G0A-
/0/a/0.0.0/1   /dev/sda1  volume         511MiB Windows FAT volume
/0/a/0.0.0/2   /dev/sda2  volume         111GiB EXT4 volume
/0/b           scsi5      storage        
/0/b/0.0.0     /dev/sdb   disk           3TB WDC WD30EZRX-00M
/0/b/0.0.0/1   /dev/sdb1  volume         2794GiB Windows NTFS volume
/1                        power          To Be Filled By O.E.M.
root@imht:/home/mirzaaliev#
```

Comment: Переустановка при форматировании разделов или поверх? Раздел один или несколько? *Желательно новую систему устанавливать на чистом отдельном разделе.*

Comment: @AlexGlebe, установка была произведена на отдельный выделенный SSD.                            Disk /dev/sda: 111,82 GiB, 120040980480 bytes, 234455040 sectors
Disk model: WDC WDS120G2G0A-
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disklabel type: gpt
Disk identifier: 69D72E2D-7DF2-4B7D-A967-2B8BFB150F4C

Device       Start       End   Sectors   Size Type
/dev/sda1     2048   1050623   1048576   512M EFI System
/dev/sda2  1050624 234452991 233402368 111,3G Linux filesystem

Comment: желательно корневой раздел сделать отдельно от **home** чтобы его отформатировать. приблизительно надо разделы такие : `/boot` 0.5G , `/` 50G , `swap` 4G , `/home` остальное. Потом `/home` можно уже не трогать .

Comment: Памяти у вас хватит, разделы не помогут. Иногда видео драйвера зависают от `GeForce GTX 550 Ti`. Надо конкретно установит для него драйвер. "390 driver using Ubuntu’s Software&Updates application"

Comment: @AlexGlebe спасибо за потраченное время. Но у меня еще вопрос я зашел Ubuntu’s Software&Updates application" и там мне предложили несколько вариантов драйверов и я в замешательстве Вы мне предлагаете скачать 390 driver, а в списке есть 460(proprietary, tested )

Comment: @andreymal на что я там должен обратить внимание ?

Comment: @AlexGlebe Если проблема в видео карте(драйвере). Может ее вообще демонтировать?!